# Button click counter on mail sent using php

Tags: php, email, campaign-monitor, click-counting

I am sending invitation mails using php `mail()`. I want to track how many people accept invitation and declined invitation. I am using two buttons for accept and decline. How can I implement click counter? Is it possible update count without redirecting page from mail to my website?

Comment: It's not possible to update the count without redirecting to your page. Because somewhere the data has to be saved... Create a file increasing the number in it with every accepted invitation.

Comment: Read [Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/).

Comment: Can I know read and unread mails using Gmail API?

Answer (score 2):

Create a file on your server: `counter`
create a PHP file which increases or decreases the number in the `counter` file.

Increase:

```
$readf = fopen("counter", "r");             //open the file in read mode
$count = fread($readf,filesize("counter")); //read the content in it
fclose($readf);                             //close the file in read mode
$writef = fopen("counter", "w+");           //open the file in overwrite mode
$count++;                                   //increase the count by one
fwrite($writef, $count);                    //write changes to the file
fclose($writef);                            //close the file in overwriting mode
```

Decrease:

```
$readf = fopen("counter", "r");
$count = fread($readf,filesize("counter"));
fclose($readf);
$writef = fopen("counter", "w+");
$count--;
fwrite($writef, $count);
fclose($writef);
```

Make sure the file `counter` exists in the first place with the count 0:

```
if(!filesize("count")){
$writef = fopen("counter", "w+");
    fwrite($writef, "0");
    fclose($writef);
}
```